# Taylor Series for $\sin (x^2) $ centered at $a = \frac{ \pi}{2}$.

Tags: calculus

I found the Taylor Series for  $\sin (x) $ centered at $a = \frac{ \pi}{2}$.  I got the series to be $\sum_{n=0} \frac{ (-1)^n (x - \frac{ \pi}{2} )^{2n} }{ (2n)!}$.

Then used substitution to find the Taylor Series for $\sin (x^2) $ centered at $a = \frac{ \pi}{2}$ to be $\sum_{n=0} \frac{ (-1)^n (x^2 - \frac{ \pi}{2} )^{2n} }{ (2n)!}$.

Would this be the correct approach?

Comment: Do you mean "centered at $x = \frac\pi 2$"?

Comment: No, you should get a series of powers of $x-\pi/2$, while you got a series of powers of $x^2-\pi/2$.

Comment: @MarkFischler I think she/he means "around $\frac{\pi}{2}$".

Comment: Neither of these series expansions are correct! You cannot simply replace $x$ in the series expansion of $\sin{x}$ with $(x-\frac\pi2)$ AND this is the Taylor series expansion for $\cos{x}$ so I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: The question is more interesting if the expansion point is $\sqrt{\frac\pi 2}$. Otherwise, the seites has messy terms involving trig functions of $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

Comment: If you need to obtain $\sin(x^2)=\sum_na_n(x-\pi/2)^n$, you can instead compute the Taylor series at the origin of $\sin((x+\pi/2)^2)=\sum_na_nx^n$, because the coefficients of the two are the same. The latter could be done in many ways. You could use the formulas for sinus sum to break $\sin((x+\pi/2)^2)=\sin(x^2+\pi x+\pi^2/4)$ into trigonometrix functions of $x^2, \pi x$ and $\pi^2/4$. Or you can compute the coefficients by taking successive derivatives. The derivatives may not look pretty at first, by they satisfy a simple recurrence equation.

Comment: In my class we say centered at "a = pi/2", but yes, we could also say centered at "x = pi/2"

Comment: Why is the first Taylor series of sin(x) incorrect?

Comment: Can I find the taylor series of sinx centered around pi/2 and then use substitution and replace the x with x^2?

Comment: The Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ centered at $a=0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. Recall that $\sin(x)$ is an odd function. This implies that its Taylor coefficients for the even degrees are zero. If you replace $x$ by $x-\pi/2$ what you are obtaining is the series of $\sin(x-\pi/2)$ centered at $\pi/2$. note that if you replace the variable on one side of the equation $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, then you need to replace it also in the other.

Comment: Yes, but i have the series centered at pi/2 so I was getting what I had above.

Comment: If you plug the first series into wolframalpha, it computes it as sin(x). I've checked multiple times and believe the first series is correct.

Comment: @user394412 Read the comment slowly and compare it with what you wrote before you add any "yes, but". Here it is you who lacks the knowledge and is seeking for it. So, take what you are being told and study it for some time.

Comment: I'm not trying to obtain the series of sin(x-pi/2) centered at pi/2. I'm trying to compute the series of sin(x) centered at pi/2 and then asked if I could just change the x to x^2

Comment: If you "find the Taylor series of $\sin{x}$ centered around $\pi/2$ and then use substitution and replace the $x$ with $x^2$" you'll get a valid series, but it won't be a Taylor series.  As others have said, this will give you a series in terms of powers of $(x^2-\pi/2)$ instead of powers of $(x-\pi/2).$

Comment: Could someone please write out a solution. I'm very confused.

Comment: @user394412 Everybody here understands what you are trying to do, that what you did is wrong, and I have told you how what you need to do should be done. I told you already to look carefully to what I said. Since you haven't done so and are still with your 'but, but, but' you will not get any further help from me. Have fun learning by not listening to what you are being taught.